# Create table trouble in MySQL 4.1

Tags: mysql, char, varchar, mysql4

The column which defined with char type in a create table sentence is defined as varchar()
It was defined as char(8)  convert to varchar (8) in desc on DB.
char(1) -> char(1) on same DB

When it defined a table of the char type more than 2 bytes,  to convert for varchar() 
is  specifications in MySQL 4.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The critical number of bytes is 3, and it only happens if the table has variable-length rows in general.  [See the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/silent-column-changes.html) for full detail.